# Apache Cassandra - Connect from other machine

Tags: cassandra, rpc

I could not connect the Cassandra from other machines but I could connect it from same machine.

I am using Hector Java client. I have already changed the rpc_address in the cassandra.yaml file.

Please give any suggestion. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like firewall. Can you ping the machine? If yes, is the service listening on the right port? (`telnet ip 9160`)

Comment: yes rigth @Jiri Kremser ; along with above checks also try adding this line in cassandra-env.sh file : JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<public name>

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: @Jiri : I could ping that machine from other machine. I am accessing the linux machine from my eclipse in windows.

Comment: @Theo : What do you mean turning it off and on ? Do you mean machine restart ?

Comment: @user2560319 And what about the telnet command, is it responding as well? If you don't have the telnet enabled, you can enable it.(http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/910.how-to-enable-telnet-client-in-windows-7.aspx)

Comment: @Jiri: No, telnet command is not responding. It says "connecting to xx.xx.xx.xx(ipaddress) Could not open connection to the host, on port 9160: Connect failed". But again I tried with ping xx.xx.xx.xx , Its pinging properly. Is there any problem in that linux machine ?

Comment: @user2560319 yes, the port is not open. If you run the following command: `iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 9169 -j ACCEPT` as a root on the linux machine, it should work. I would also try if the service is accessible from the linux machine itself `telnet localhost 9160`.

Comment: @Jiri I ran the command in the linux machine but no positive response. I will try telnet command and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, My firewall is blocking off the telnet port and probably the rest of the ports cassandra needs. You need to add an exception telling the firewall to open port 9160 (the client port). 9160 is the only port you really need to have open unless you want remote jmx management etc.

To add an exception to your linux firewall:

iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 9160 --syn -j ACCEPT

And if you want to save the state:

service iptables save